# Flutter back button pressed, not hide the keyboard on Android 10

Tags: android, flutter

Usually, if we press the back button, the keyboard will hide, but as in this video, when repeatedly pressing the back button, the keyboard is not hidden. But in the test on Android 7, it worked fine, when I pressed the hidden keyboard back button.

Like this
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/11581453/94370563-64b50480-0123-11eb-9329-4a52aaeb6aaa.gif

this is my input code

```
TextFormField(
  validator: (e) {
    var message;
    if (e.isEmpty) {
      message = emailEmpty;
    }
    return message;
  },
  onSaved: (e) => email = e,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    prefixIcon: Icon(
      Icons.email,
      color: Color(0xFF003d64),
    ),
    labelText: emailInput,
  ),
),
```

`flutter doctor -v`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.22.0-12.1.pre, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G2021, locale en-ID)
    • Flutter version 1.22.0-12.1.pre at / Users / abedputra / Development / flutter
    • Framework revision 8b3760638a (12 days ago), 2020-09-15 17:47:13 -0700
    • Engine revision 4654fc6cf6
    Dart version 2.10.0 (build 2.10.0-110.3.beta)

 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at / Users / abedputra / Library / Android / sdk
    • Android-R platform, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: / Applications / Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at / Applications / Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at / Applications / Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 50.0.2-dev.1
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • K88 (mobile) 6acdf2f6 android-arm64 Android 7.1.1 (API 25)
    • Web Server (web) • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 85.0.4183.121
```

Comment: can you please provide your `flutter doctor -v`?

Comment: @AbhishekGhaskata updated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already fix [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/66791) from the Flutter Github page.

To fix it change from the **Beta** channel to the **Stable** or **Master** channel.

***Update***

Flutter releases a new version at Beta `channel 1.22.0 • channel beta` (2020-10-01) and the issue already fixed.

Thanks

Answer (score -2):

try add dispose method to your class State (Widget) :

```
    @override
      void dispose() {
        // TODO: implement dispose
        super.dispose();
      }
```

Comment: Can you please explain why would a solution like this will ever work?